# Risky Connection?

Tags: security

While browsing on Tor this evening. I received a message from either windows security center or mcafee stating that they had blocked a "risky connection" coming from an "anonymous proxy" I didnt get a chance to write the message down in its entirety because I was browsing some fairly sensitive information and got scared and closed all my windows. The most disturbing part was that it referenced somewhere in my tor folders for the location of this threat and rated it at "Very High"

I reinstalled Tor today and had been browsing a lot of questionable onion sites with javascript off since my reinstall (really wish this was disabled automatically). I was under the impression that Mcafee/Windows security had nothing to do with my Tor connection. ANY input would be GREATLY appreciated as I am (obviously) not very tech savvy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it was Mcafee you'll almost certainly have logs of the event that you can review. Poke around the software for a bit to see if you can find any relevant info

Comment: It was in fact the Mcafee firewall, however I cannot get any details on this specific threat. When I view the logs it will show me (100+) blocked connections from today alone likely (in my opinion which could mean little) due to the fact I'm using windows 8 and I havent allowed my computer to connect to my microsoft account. The threat however is logged under the firewall, which I cannot get any details about. I'm getting frustrated.

Comment: There were many blocked connections form different IPs with different explainations, this one caught my interest "The PC XXX.XXX.X.X tried to access your system UDP port 1900. If you want to allow this traffic, either trust the IP address or open the port in the System Services in Firewall.  UDP port 1900 is commonly used by the "SSDP" service or program. SSDP is used to install remote installation services. The protocol was designed to simplify administration by allowing yo to install a device on your LAN and in turn have it install itself onto all computers on the LAN....

Comment: The original implimentation was flawed and exposed a security risk.--skip a bunch of text---However opening port 1900 to the internet is generally not wise even on a patched system.  If you are on a school lan or share several systems you may see three events per system every few minutes. This can be ignored. If you do not see three items from the same system (on average) then you may wish to report this as an attack. If you need to open this port is can be opened via 'system services'...The source IP address is your own gateway. The source IP address is on your own DHCP server& lcl network

Comment: Doubting this is related because when i looked at the threat initially the threat was shown on the map as an "anonymous proxy" that showed coming from somewhere in africa on the threat map.

Comment: I think ive looked through all 130 or so "suspicious incoming network connections" but I dont think any of these are it, many say the PC "XX.XXX.XX" tried to connect to TCP Port 50XXX (many variations of this port starting with 50) without your permission

Comment: I ALSO SHOULD ADD, I was not able to type into my browser anywhere following this and had to restart my computer for any functionality to return, this computer is maybe only a month old and this had not happened prior.

Comment: If you can add a screenshot or copy of the message to your question it would really help us answer.

Comment: FINALLY found where this threat is listed. Was listed under Net Guard, separate from the other potential threats, my apologies. IP ADDRESS: 37.130.227.133 Last Connection Attempt: 12/15/2013 Action: Block Last attempted by: tor.exe I am very disappointed that this was not logged with all the info that it displayed when the threat first happened (especially the exact file location that this stemmed from?) Hope this is enough info for some help!